# chisq.test with R

Tags: r, distributions, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, weibull-distribution

I want to do a Goodness-of-Fit test of my data and the Weibull-distribution.
I have estimated the Weibull distribution using the `survreg`-function in R.

Now I want to check if the fit of both densities is significant. I want to use the chisq.test.

Can somebody help me with the arguments for that test?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you mean `survreg`? What do you mean by "the fit of both densities"? What is the null hypothesis you are trying to test and what is the purpose of testing it?

Comment: Yes, I mean survreg, I am sorry. I have a sample of lifespan data. My null hypothesis is: The sample follows a weibull distribution. The purpose is that I assumed that my sample follows a weibull distribution and I now want to check if that is correct. But I am not sure if the chisq.test is the right test for that

Comment: No test will tell you it is correct.

Comment: Have you tried the fitdistrplus package?

Comment: library(fitdistrplus)
fitdist(YOURDATA, distr="weibull", method="mle") 

Should do the trick. I think there's also functions in that package (or maybe mc2d) to generate a Cullen-Frey plot to explore some other distribution fits quickly.